# Chronological list of installed packages

Tags: software-installation

How can I get in Ubuntu 14.04 a list of every program I have installed with its size but with chronological order? Is there a way?

It is important to mention that I have found a lot of similar questions in here and they were not helpful.

Comment: Take a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12578/list-packages-by-installation-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will show you the list of installed software in chronological order.

```
ls -l --time=ctime --time-style=long-iso /usr/share/applications|sort -r -k6|grep "\.desktop"|sed s/'\.desktop.*'//g|awk '{print $6" "$7" "$8}'
```

The output will be like

```
2015-03-09 17:36 eclipse_java
2015-03-09 17:34 eclipse_cpp
2015-02-27 17:34 system-config-printer
2015-02-27 17:34 nautilus-home
2015-02-27 17:34 nautilus-folder-handler
2015-02-27 17:34 nautilus
2015-02-27 17:34 nautilus-connect-server
2015-02-27 17:34 nautilus-classic
2015-02-27 17:34 nautilus-autorun-software
2015-02-27 17:34 mount-archive
2015-02-27 17:31 unity-activity-log-manager-panel
2015-02-27 17:31 firefox
2015-02-27 17:31 compiz
2015-02-27 17:31 ccsm
...
...
...
...
2014-08-14 18:15 eog
2014-08-14 18:15 empathy
2014-08-14 18:15 deja-dup-preferences
2014-08-14 18:15 deja-dup
2014-08-14 18:15 debian-xterm
2014-08-14 18:15 debian-uxterm
2014-08-14 18:15 credentials-preferences
2014-08-14 18:15 cheese
2014-08-14 18:15 checkbox-gui
2014-08-14 18:15 brasero-nautilus
2014-08-14 18:15 brasero
2014-08-14 18:15 baobab
2014-08-14 18:15 apturl
```

As far as size of software is concerned, it is difficult to say what the size of software will be, as the files are spread in many places and are many times shared between softwares.